# Neo4j Query Optimization for Cartesian Product

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to implement a user-journey analytics solution. Simply analyze on which screens, which users leave the application. 
For this , I have modeled the data like this:
[image: blue circles are events (a single activity that contains user and device data). green circles are event types (activity types such as the name of the screen)]
I modeled single activity since I want to index some attributes. Relation attributes can not be indexed in Neo4j.

With this model, I am trying to write a query that follows three successive event types with below query:

```
MATCH (eventType1:EventType {eventName:'viewStart-home'})<--(event:EventNode)
<--(eventType2:EventType{eventName:'viewStart-payment'})  

WITH distinct event.deviceId as eUsers, event.clientCreationDate as eDate

MATCH((eventType2)<--(event2:EventNode)
<--(eventType3:EventType{eventName:'viewStart-screen1'}))

WITH distinct event2.deviceId as e2Users, event2.clientCreationDate as e2Date
RETURN e2Users limit 200000
```

And the execution plan is below:

[image: last NodeByLabelScan ruins everything]

I could not figure the reason of this process out. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is doing a lot more work than it needs to.

The first `WITH` clause is not needed at all, since its generated `eUsers` and `eDate` variables are never used. And the second `WITH` clause does not need to generate the unused `e2Date` variable.

In addition, you could first add an index for `:EventType(eventName)` to speed up the processing:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :EventType(eventName);
```

With these changes, your query's profile could be simpler and the processing would be faster.

Here is an updated query (that should use the index to quickly find the `EventType` node at one end of the path, to kick off the query):

```
MATCH (:EventType {eventName:'viewStart-home'})<--(:EventNode)
  <--(:EventType{eventName:'viewStart-payment'})<--(event2:EventNode)
  <--(:EventType{eventName:'viewStart-screen1'})
RETURN distinct event2.deviceId as e2Users
LIMIT 200000;
```

Here is an alternate query that uses 2 `USING INDEX` hints to tell the planner to quickly find the `:EventType` nodes at *both* ends of the path to kick off the query. This might be even faster than the first query:

```
MATCH (a:EventType {eventName:'viewStart-home'})<--(:EventNode)
  <--(:EventType{eventName:'viewStart-payment'})<--(event2:EventNode)
  <--(b:EventType{eventName:'viewStart-screen1'})
USING INDEX a:EventType(eventName)
USING INDEX b:EventType(eventName)
RETURN distinct event2.deviceId as e2Users
LIMIT 200000;
```

Try profiling them both on your DB, and pick the best one or keep tweaking further.